# writing groovy script for REST service in SOAP UI

Tags: xml, rest, groovy, soapui

I am trying to get the response from the REST service in a groovy script as following:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("REST-options-Default#Response")
```

where  `"REST-options-Default"` is the test step name.

but getting the following error:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:error: Unexpected element:CDATA
```

the same is working in case of SOAP.

please advise.

Comment: What does the response xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use responseAsXml instead of response. Change your code in order to avoid XmlException:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("REST-options-Default#responseAsXml")
```

Depends on request type you must use response or responseAsXml property, for example in **soap test request** works with **response** but not with **responseAsXml**, however with **jdbc test request** works with **responseAsXml** but not with **response**.

Hope this helps,